# Why is the age of the universe important?

Tags: cosmology, time, universe, big-bang

Age may only be a number, but when it comes to the age of the universe, it's a pretty important one. Why?

Comment: because nobody can be older than universe :-)

Comment: I find it unclear what you are asking. "Why?" in which respect? The age of the Universe is important, if you are interested in the History of the Universe, much like an archeologist would be interested by the age of his discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Science progresses by explaining newly discovered phenomena that don't fit existing models.

When we discovered the [Metushelah Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_140283) that looked like it may be older than the Universe it made us think harder about some assumptions, models and measurements we had.

The exact age of the universe is not that important but the early evolution of the Universe is an extremely important to our understanding of fundamental physics and may help in our search of the [Theory of Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything)